# How to initialize a shared_ptr that is a member of a class?

Tags: c++, boost, initialization, shared-ptr, member

I am not sure about a good way to initialize a `shared_ptr` that is a member of a class. Can you tell me, whether the way that I choose in `C::foo()` is fine, or is there a better solution?

```
class A
{
  public:
    A();
};

class B
{
  public:
    B(A* pa);
};

class C
{
    boost::shared_ptr<A> mA;
    boost::shared_ptr<B> mB;
    void foo();
};

void C::foo() 
{
    A* pa = new A;
    mA = boost::shared_ptr<A>(pa);
    B* pB = new B(pa);
    mB = boost::shared_ptr<B>(pb);
}
```

Comment: chubsdad: Won't work in members, only in ctors.

Comment: @MSalters: I have no idea what you're trying to say.

Comment: In the original question I am talking about a function foo(), and not about a constructor. So initialization lists don't fit.

Comment: While its usually better to initialize members in constructors, your code works. But what are you asking exactly then ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your code is quite correct (it works), but you can use the initialization list, like this:

```
C::C() :
  mA(new A),
  mB(new B(mA.get())
{
}
```

Which is even more correct and as safe.

If, for whatever reason, `new A` or `new B` throws, you'll have no leak.

If `new A` throws, then no memory is allocated, and the exception aborts your constructor as well. Nothing was constructed.

If `new B` throws, and the exception will still abort your constructor: `mA` will be destructed properly.

Of course, since an instance of `B` requires a pointer to an instance of `A`, the declaration order of the members **matters**.

The member declaration order is correct in your example, but if it was reversed, then your compiler would probably complain about `mB` beeing initialized before `mA` and the instantiation of `mB` would likely fail (since `mA` would not be constructed yet, thus calling `mA.get()` invokes undefined behavior).

---

I would also suggest that you use a `shared_ptr<A>` instead of a `A*` as a parameter for your `B` constructor (**if** it makes senses and if you can accept the little overhead). It would probably be safer.

Perhaps it is guaranteed that an instance of `B` cannot live without an instance of `A` and then my advice doesn't apply, but we're lacking of context here to give a definitive advice regarding this.

Comment: Given that you're relying on it, it's worth talking about the how the order of construction of members works and the sequence points involved.

Comment: @ereOn - A return type for a constructor ?

Comment: @DumbCoder: Copied from the question where it's also wrong. I fixed it.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: The order of construction actually doesn't matter. If B were constructed first, or even if it were random, it would still be exception-safe. That is a result of non-overlapping construction, not order. Non-overlap implies that at each point where new memory is allocated, previously allocated memory is managed by a fully-constructed subobject.

Comment: @MSalters: If the initializer for `mB` includes the call `mA.get()` (which it does) then the order of initialization very much does matter.

Comment: @MSalters: Just to be clear on what I originally meant: while the answer is correct as written, it hasn't been made completely clear why it's correct. If the order of declaration of `mA` and `mB` were reversed in the class definition then it may not be clear why `C() : mA(new A), mB(new B(mA.get())) {}` is incorrect.

Comment: @sbi: I indeed copied it from the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: Edited my answer so it is more precise regarding the initialization order. (At least I hope so). Feel free to correct it if something seems wrong. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm with Charles on this. I usually try to prevent for a ctor to rely on the order of members to be initialized. If I can't avoid it, I put a __big and scary comment next to those members' definitions__.

Comment: The shared_ptr<MyClass> = new MyClass syntax doesn't seem to work for me:

#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

struct MyClass{};

int
main (int argc, char** argv)
{
 boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> MyClassPtr;

 MyClassPtr = new MyClass;
 return(0);
}
I get "no match for operator=".

Comment: @DavidDoria: Please post a new question regarding your problem and I will be happy to answer it. Comments on SO are not for asking new questions.