# boost shared_ptr initialize as class member

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, intel-edison

I am having a problem initializing a `boost::shared_ptr` when it is a member variable of a class. I saw this previous question:

[How to initialize a shared_ptr that is a member of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545450/how-to-initialize-a-shared-ptr-that-is-a-member-of-a-class)

However I still have a compiler error. Quick example code:

```
class A
{
    public:
      A();
};

class B
{
    public:
       B();
    private:
        boost::shared_ptr<A> mA;

        foo() {

           // the line below generates a compiler error
           mA(new A());       // ERROR

           // below will work....
           boost::shared_ptr<A> tmp(new A());    //OK
           mA = tmp;

        }
 };
```

The compiler complains with:
`error: no match for call to "(boost::shared_ptr<A>)  (A*)"`

However creating a tmp `shared_ptr` and then assigning it to `mA` compiles fine. I am cross-compiling on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine for an Intel Edison.

What am I missing?

Comment: Use the constructor initializer list - `foo() : mA(new A()) {...}` or `foo() : mA(boost::make_shared<A>()) {...}`

Comment: This has **nothing** to do with `shared_ptr`, if `mA` was an `int` then you would have the same problem trying to do `mA(0)` in the constructor body. Members are already initialized by the time the constructor body starts, so you either need to initialize them earlier (in the mem-initializer list) or assign to them in the body. Get a good book on C++.

Comment: I disagree. If mA was an int I would have used the mem-initializer list, or set it in the constructor body, ma = 2 or whatever. It was my ignorance of initializing a shared_ptr, that I posted the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `mA.reset(new A());`

Also shared pointer is part of the standard now, so you should use [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

Comment: This took care of it. Thanks. switched over to std::shared_ptr also